# Copy constructors

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why should the copy constructor accept its parameter by reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685854/why-should-the-copy-constructor-accept-its-parameter-by-reference-in-c)
>   [Why is copy constructor not allowed pass by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8436467/why-is-copy-constructor-not-allowed-pass-by-value)

I am reading the lecture notes for my class on C++.  In the notes they say the copy constructor signature for a class is

> MyClass(MyClass &other)

and

> MyClass(MyClass other)

won't work.  Why is that?

Thank you!

Comment: Exactly what does a copy constructor do?  Exactly what happens in the invocation of `MyClass(MyClass other)`?

Comment: Don't forget the `const`. A better signature for a copy constructor is `MyClass(const MyClass& other)`.

Comment: Actually, the copy contructor should be `MyClass(const MyClass& other)`.

Comment: @Paul: It doesn't have to be `const`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I said "should". And it should.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: It doesn't have to be, but it should be unless there's a good reason. Especially in teaching material.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Paul is correct. If you want to modify your parameter, then why create a copy of it and be able to modify the original?

Comment: @Adel: I'm aware that there's probably no good reason to do so.  My point was merely that the C++ standard explicitly allows a non-const reference as the parameter to a copy constructor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `MyClass(MyClass other)` is passing the parameter by value, which itself requires a copy to be created.  This would lead to an infinite loop (terminated only when your stack overflows).

Answer (score 3):

This is because in order to pass an instance of `MyClass other` to a constructor with the second signature the constructor would need to call itself, resulting in infinite recustion leading to stack overflow.

Try it out, this is a very instructive exercise!

Answer (score 2):

`MyClass(MyClass other)` is passing `other` by copy, which would invoke the copy constructor, which you are defining, thus you would end up with infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1):

`MyClass(MyClass other)` is already creating a copy of `other` because you are passing the parameter `other` as **variable** not as **reference**, so the copy constructor in this case would be meaningless

Answer (score 1):

Valid copy constructor signatures are

`MyClass(MyClass &other)` 
`MyClass(const MyClass &other)` 
`MyClass(MyClass const &other)`

In C++ all function parameters are passed by value. This means that if you'll pass `other` by value it will be destroyed after the function call operator finishes.
Moreover, in case of copy constructor infinite loop of copy constructor execution will be met.
So copy constructor parameter is always passed by reference.

Comment: The second two are identical...

Comment: Yep. They're identical from the compiler POV, but not from the human one :) So, let them both be for the newcomers eyes.

Comment: @badatmath:  If a variable or reference is `const`, it cannot be used to change a value.  In this case, the `const` means that the function will not modify `other`.  (As in most things in C++, there's ways around this, but let's not worry about them now.)